# How to create a Rule on Drupal that creates activity streams of followed users?

Tags: drupal

I'm using Flags, Commons follow, Message and Rules modules to create the ability for users to follow each other.

I use commons auto generated commons_follow_user flag to create a follow button. I generate that button through views on each node. If user A presses the button on the node submitted by user B, user A starts following user B. By default commons follow user module shows user B name on user A account page. What I also need is for user A to see activity stream of the user B, more specifically to see when user B adds new node. I understand that I have to use rules and messages modules. I have created a rule that triggers Message entity creation on new node creation but how do I make this stream only visible to users following the user that creates those nodes? Is there a way with rule conditions? Or should I look in the other direction to achieve this?

Comment: This is a question that better suits Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create some sort of social network.

A module I'm pretty fond of us the [Statuses module](http://drupal.org/project/statuses)

If you're just looking for something that will post activity, there's also the [heartbeat module](http://drupal.org/project/heartbeat)

I hope that helps.